# Change datetime to current user UTC

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to change datetime to users UTC.

**e.g**

```
date = anydate (2017-11-03)
time = currenttime (Time.now)
Time.zone = current_user.time_zone
Required = date +  time (to current_user.timezone)
```

Comment: `Time.Now` should be `Time.now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse date & time in the user's time zone:

```
date = '2017-11-03'
time = Time.now
Time.zone = current_user.time_zone

required = Time.zone.parse(date + ' ' + time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date = "2017-11-03"
user_date = date.to_datetime
zone = current_user.time_zone
user_date.in_time_zone(zone)
```

for example: -

```
"2017-11-03".to_datetime.in_time_zone("Chennai")
=> Fri, 03 Nov 2017 05:30:00 IST +05:30
```

Comment: Note: `date.to_datetime` will not consider the current time.

Comment: @AshikSalman thanks for correct me. :) there is a typo in above answer, `time = Time.Now` it should be `Time.now` kindly modify it for future searchers.

Comment: My bad (copied from question), It is there in original post as well :-). Thanks, I will update answer.